# CSS Animation / Transition Rotate Logo (Steps)

Tags: css, css-transitions, animate.css

I'm begining about CSS Animation / Transition.

I ask for help. I want to obtain this effects:

Image Logo which:

1. it will rotate 180 degrees in 1 second
2. it will rotate by a further 180 degrees in 2 seconds
3. it will be motionless for the next 3 seconds
4. with each mouseover it will change into a blurry form

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code?

Comment: Hello, We are not here to code the whole thing for you. Give us some example code. It will be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: There are pages were you can get job done.. https://www.topcoder.com/...,

Comment: Why is people giving answers for this, this is pretty code for me please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be saying what you've tried and give an example, anyway, this is what i've come up with (in css):

```
@keyframes rotation {
    0%   { transform: rotate(0deg);}
    16%  {transform: rotate(180deg);} 
    50%  {transform: rotate(360deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

.foo {
    filter: blur(0px);
    animation-name: rotation;
    animation-duration: 6s;
}
.foo:hover {
    filter blur(3px);
}
```